# how set date in a particular format in java

Tags: java

I am reading the date from a excel file ,while reading i am getting the date in desired format
 but while printing in console i am getting in different forma.
Please help.

Code For reading is

```
if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) { //Date
                                if ((cell.getDateCellValue()) != null) {

                                     excelPojo.setAsOfDate(cell.getDateCellValue());

                                }
                            }
```

while printing getting this

```
Date As of===Tue Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 2013
```

But i want it, in this format - 31-dec-2013

please help

Comment: Did you check SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Use a search engine "format data java".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
System.out.println(format.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to print date with you're desired format

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
System.out.println("Date : " + format.format(date));
```

Read more about [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.YOUR_LOCALE);
df.format(yourDate);
```

For details look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use DateFormat to format the date in any format.

refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html